# polymer iron list update after splice

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have array for `iron-list`, and when I push something with `this.push('myArray', item)`, my `iron-list` will update, but with the same situation using splice, `this.splice('myArray', itemIndex, 1)`, `iron-list` won't update.

Any thought? What is proper way to do this?

Comment: try adding `this.notifyPath('myArray', this.myArray);`

Comment: Can you post a plunker or something like that?

Comment: I found that doing `this.push` after `this.splice` update list, so if I will delete last index and place something in the same place, list will change properly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

```
 this.myArray = this.splice('myArray', itemIndex, 1)
```

In order to see if this.myArray actually changes. Add an observer inside that property